# Is it possible to disable the Pull Result message box of eGit in Eclipse?

Tags: git, eclipse, egit, git-pull

It really annoys me that after each pull I get in Eclipse using eGit I receive a message box of the result.

I do not want to see it unless there are problems. Is there a way to configure that?

Ironically, the message box does not appear when there are problems requiring merging...

Answer (score 0):

In *Window > **Preferences: Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings*** in the *Show result dialogs after git remote operations* section **uncheck** the ***Fetch Result Dialog*** checkbox for that.

You get the dialog for the fetch result, which is triggered by the pull. There are dialogs only for remote operations since these may take a while. But I understand your point and you might suggest it as an improvement.

Comment: Thanks, I unchecked mentioned option a while ago, but it did not seem to have any effect. Maybe it is a bug in my version of egit.

Comment: @JRA_TLL You should have JGit/EGit 5.9. If not, please upgrade.